# How to add an identifier in a row if any cell for that row is changed in excel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

Is there a way in excel to mark the rows with an **identifier** if any cell in that row is **changed** without using **vb scripts** and using a **formula** ?

Such that while parsing the excel, i can get only those rows which are **changed** and then i can easily compare those changed rows with the values in the database.

The reason i need to do that is because:

1. It is a bulk import and each sheet can have **50,000 to million rows**.
2. Data in each row needs to compare with 3-4 database tables
3. I cannot add **vb scripts** to those excel sheets because the excel sheets are exported through the same application.

Or is there any other way to efficiently do the bulk import? I'm using the **Roo** gem and already using the **each_row_streaming** method.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That is still not a question by any means.

Comment: I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there exists no such functionality. Even in the case you would use VBA to mark changed rows, you would run into a validation issues. Let me explain a bit:

Let A be the one changing the data, if she is not such a nice lady she will make her necessary changes but fiddle around with the change indications to break you logic. Why? Because she can. Or because it gives her a business advantage, or ... Even if she is nice, how do you now - for certain - that no change went unnoticed?

I would say your safe option is to always do a full compare on each workbook/row against the database to be sure no change goes unnoticed.

It might be sensible to calculate a hash for each row and store it somewhere in the database. That way you would only need to recompute and compare the hashes. But this depends a lot on your data.

Comment: Thats what i'm doing. Also "She" here is very nice and is the owner. If any way is possible to put something in row using a formula to know it has been changed?

Comment: What maybe could be done to speed things up is export the previous and the current excel to csv (or some other text based format) and run a diff-program on those files. This could give you a list of changes row numbers.

Comment: Marking as an accepted answer because there is no solution yet for the problem.